# Table view or table view cell width is not fitting correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I tried to place one view controller and I place table view inside my view controller and set the top, bottom, left, right to 0 constraints. But when I place any cell with any elements like button, label it is coming half only.

Only coming for 5s, for other screens its the cell width is reducing.

I used preview help to check whats the issue..image attached below. But don't know why its coming like this. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run the app on iphone 7 or 7 plus (simulators)?

Comment: Have you tried run the app on the simulator or on a device? Can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Did you set your constraints for the elements of the table view cell? Where is the cell in your image?

Comment: can you put screenshot of storyboard? when constraints are appears.

Comment: @NilayShah  @ Lorenzo B  See my post..after i set the button at right with 8px constaints..its good for 5s...But in other screen..its not in correct postion...dont know wethere its an cell problem ?

Comment: @doubtman please post screenshot of trailing and bottom constraints of UITableview.

Comment: when you add constraint 0,0,0,0 of tableview than you have to uncheck Constraint to margins

Comment: Have you set constraints to cell? If yes, then remove the constraints of cell & controls(button, label) inside it and apply constraints again. I think your issue is only due to mismatch of constraints. Do you see any yellow or red indication in your document outline, showing incorrect constraints?

Comment: @ Nishant Bhindi  i am not getting what u saysing..when i set constraint 0,0,0,0 i have set its fine....please cehck my pos

Comment: @Apogee   i din get constraints for cell. i set only for table view and i put prototype cell from 0 to 1

Comment: @Nishant Bhindi  any solution please

Comment: try to set constraints differently. try to give tableview equal height and width to superview and set tableview centered horizontal and vertical, see if that works properly or not

Comment: @ Rishabh  i set, but the left and right and top and botom is missing..its totally coming at centre

Comment: @doubtman Please set the datasource of tableview. I just now tried. This should definitely work for you, provided that your constraints are correct.

Comment: data source means..i already set the data source and delegate method in my class ..and also set the data source and deleagate to self

Comment: @Apogee   is that datasourec is method in view controler class ??numberOfRowsInSection,cellForRowAt, didSelectRowAt  i added this 3

Comment: Check your connection inspector. Do you see the delegate and datasource connection to your viewController? Double check the name of the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Delete all yours constraints...
and in autoresizing put only Up / Down / Left / Right

[image: resizing position]